# response after ajax post request in ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, facebook, ember.js

I am new to ember .I designed an ember app and integrate the fb login in it and have to send facebook accesstoken to app backend (post request) and fetch the token generated by backend(rails).

My Post request response is:

```
{
"token":"71fcb8c39dc6449e2ac8e88d21e4d008cf746e16a774aa8755f6be0dbc43849265f9010111986a912fde60de4f76eb5a600ec286b26ea0a865cc7f5cab49330a",
"user":{"role":"unverified"}
}
```

and the component is

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    fb: Ember.inject.service(),
    session: Ember.inject.service(),

    authenticate: function(accessToken) {
    console.log("accesstoken: "+accessToken);
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/sessions/fb_login",
                accepts: 'application/json',
                data: { token: accessToken},
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {
                    'Client-Key': '403cb982d0c48473bee32b41b6765e15a26c595c689c620cece5fc15370c33c9c9f6d071f84bf6b88baf466f653f44b4524634bde6fbe68f065f06268f7ed7e2',
                },
        type: 'post',
        success:function(data){
          console.log('data is '+data);
        }
      });
  },

    actions: {

        fb_login() {
                this.get('fb').login().then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    let fbToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    this.authenticate(fbToken);
                } else if( response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // code for not authrized
                    // this.transitionTo('/');
                } else {
                    // code for facebook login
                    // this.transitionTo('/');
                } 
            }).catch(() => {
                    // this.sendAction('check','/');
            });
        },
    }

});
```

But after ajax call success is never get called to I am unable to get the the response and browser always responds with:

```
pretender.js:132 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/v1/sessions/fb_login".
```

Somebody please explain me how the ajax work in ember for api calls.

Comment: _“But after ajax call success is never get called”_ – well maybe the call _wasn’t_ a success … add an error handler as well, and see what you get then.

Comment: I checked for error but that too not get called and when I checked through chrome's inspect element in network tab I can see the the response in it which is fine. But it still not working

Comment: Maybe a CORS Problem? And i could recommend to use Promises to handle the ajax call, not a success/error handler. Use Ember.RSVP.Resolve on the jQuery ajax object.

Comment: Catch wont trigger unless you return promises. return this.get('fb').login().then().catch(() => should now trigger) Also if the code above is your fb-login it should also return the ajax request.